# After Effects expressions to sum numbers and control charts

Tags: automation, adobe-after-effects, javascript, chart-design

I would like to build a project in which I will change two numbers and all of the following take place automatically! I'll Explain...

[image]

Part 1:

I have two layers, "Number 1" and "Number 2". Suppose I give "Number 1" the value 15 and "Number 2" the value 5. Automatically I want a new layer to sum these numbers (20).

Part 2:

Next, I would like to built a chart below to update automatically according to the numbers that I gave.

From the above sum, I want the layer with the value 20 to automatically correspond to 100% in the chart. So the chart shapes change automatically and understand that "Number 1" with the value 15 is 75% (15*100/20) and "Number 2" with the value 5 is 25% (5*100/20).

Probably I need for the value of the numbers a Solid with a Numbers effect and not a text? And if someone knows the expressions...

Comment: The man you need is Rick Gerard in the Adobe AE forums. He can probably figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty easy to set up with a few expressions and control inputs. All we need is two control inputs and expressions on the various layers to pull the values from the inputs.

#### 1. Slider Control

Create a null object *(Layer → New → Null Object)* and add a slider expression control to that null object by going to *(Effect → Expression Controls → Slider Control)*. This gives us a handy slider in the Effects panel that we can use as an input in expressions.

You should have something like this:

[image]

#### 2. Text layer

Create a new text layer to show our input from the slider. Open the "Text" property and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> the stopwatch next to "Source Text" to add an expression to the text itself. The expression we need is:

```
Math.round(thisComp.layer("Val 1").effect("Slider Control")("Slider"))
```

The `Math.round()` just means we get an integer, otherwise we get a ton of decimal places. The rest simply gets the value from the slider from the correct layer.

[image]

#### 3. Putting it all together

Repeat the same steps as above for your second input (so you need a total of 2 null objects, each with a slider, and 2 text layers with an expression pulling the value from the correct slider (simply change `layer("Val 1")` in both expressions to reference the correct layer names).

For your sum total text you need another text layer with an expression pulling *both* slider values and adding the values together. Something like:

```
val1 = thisComp.layer("Val 1").effect("Slider Control")("Slider");
val2 = thisComp.layer("Val 2").effect("Slider Control")("Slider");
val1 + val2
```

#### 4. Chart bars

We can use the same concept to set up our bars. Create your bars at 100% width (you should also move the bar's anchor to the far left, or where ever you want them to scale *from*). You can then add an expression on the layer's scale property to pull in the slider values and do the calculations you already mention. Something like:

```
val1 = thisComp.layer("Val 1").effect("Slider Control")("Slider");
val2 = thisComp.layer("Val 2").effect("Slider Control")("Slider");
t = val1 + val2;

[ val2*100/t, 100 ]
```

[image]

The finished thing looks something like this; just select your null objects and adjust the sliders and everything will automatically update for you:

[image]

This was a quick example and could definitely be improved; the text could probably just be done on a single layer and the bars update on the raw slider values while the text only shows a rounded integer, which may or may not be what you want...

Actually, here's a more compact version with both sliders added to a single text layer:

[image]

You can read more about using expressions here:

- [**Learn expression basics to link animations in Adobe After Effects**](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/expression-basics.html)